# Мгновенный вывод текста из инпута в див

Tags: javascript, input, html

Как мгновенно вывести текст из инпута в див
У нас есть обычный инпут и див
Когда мы пишем любой текст в инпут, он автоматически появляеться в диве

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения задачи можно использовать событие `oninput`:

```js
function onInput() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    if (div != null && input != null)
        div.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" oninput="onInput();"/>
<div id="div" />
```

---

Возникает вопрос: а почему не `onkeyup`? По двум причинам.

Во-первых, при зажатой кнопке ввод в `input` будет продолжаться, а в `div` изменения попадут только при отпускании кнопки.

А во-вторых, ввод возможен и без помощи клавиатуры, например, вставка щелчком мыши по контекстному меню. В этом случае обработчик `onkeyup` вообще не будет вызван.

---

*P.S.* Возможны проблемы с *IE9* и более старыми (https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-input).

Comment: А как правильно вывести функцию в отдельный фаил js, когда засовываю ее в фаил, она перестает работать

Comment: @user232379 Переносим функцию в файл и подключаем его: `<script src="..."></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

На скорую руку - добавляете обработчик нажатий в вашем инпуте, который будет копировать содержимое инпута в див.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var div = document.getElementById("div");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  div.innerText = input.value;
})
```

```css
#div {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<div id="div"></div>
```